# Multiprocessing - How to detect when process has successfully started?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

After doing `process.start()`, how can my code detect once the process has successfully launched?

So I've tried using queues to send a message to the `main process` from the `child process` but that just means i have to use `process.join()` and that would halt any other tasks in my `main process`.

I'm not sure if there's a easy way to do this.. But I would assume that you would have to get the PID of the child process and do a process scan on your system to find that PID right?

I know there isn't much work done here on my part, but I'm seriously at a lost. I tried searching everywhere on google with no answers.

Comment: `Process` objects have an [`is_alive()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.is_alive) method to check their status.

Comment: @martineau Hi. That didn't work. After executing `process.start()`, my process takes about 10 seconds to start. i did a while loop on the main process after i launched it and all it shows was "True" while the child process haven't showed up on my screen yet :(

Comment: The child process is started as soon as you call `process.start()`. The fact that it does not show on the screen is irrelevant. That is because the process is slow and it takes some time for it to show up. But it is started anyway.

Comment: nenese: Since it sounds like your own definition of "started" means the process has reached the point where it can put a message in a `Queue`, you could check for that having happened in the main process without blocking by calling [`Queue.get_nowait()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue.get_nowait).